# web2py - test for row with combination of two field values

Tags: python, web2py

I'm building a web2py controller in which I need to query a table for a combination of value x in one field AND value y in a second field (in the same row). To query on a single field, I would just write

```
db.table.field == x
```

But I don't know how to write a query that looks for `field==x AND field2==y`

Comment: Have you tried `(db.table.field == x)&(db.table.field2 == y)` ? It's been a while since I've done web2py stuff but I thought that was how it worked...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(db.table.field1==x)&(db.table.field2==y)
```

See the book section on [logical operators](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#Logical-Operators).

Answer (score 1):

For a more advanced version, you can append a query to a list and use python's reduce function.

```
queries=[]
if arg1 == "x": queries.append(db.table.field == x)
if arg2 == "y": queries.append(db.table.otherfield == y)
# many conditions here....
query = reduce(lambda a,b:(a&b),queries)
db(query).select()
```